# How to change focus-mode: mouse's delay?

Tags: mouse, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

How can I change delay before focus when having focus-mode: mouse in gnome 3?

I am used to this behaviour from my previous WM (awesome), but I decided to give a Gnome another try (last used was gnome2) and I havem more or less happy so far, only this mouse focus thing is bugging me. I am used to no delay when focusing window under mouse, but I cannot find any setting do to this in gnome3.

I so far tried googling, some medling with dconf editor but so far I have no luck in solving this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change this by **disabling the option `focus-change-on-pointer-rest` in schema `org.gnome.shell.overrides`** (which overrides the original option in `org.gnome.mutter` while GNOME Shell is running).

But note that this might actually have more downsides than you expect.

When this option is enabled, there is a hardcoded delay of 25 milliseconds "to check whether the pointer has stopped moving after a crossing event", added in [commit 59bc5b7](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=678169) in response to [bug report 678169](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=678169).

```
commit 59bc5b7975f1f19ebacb520c1c2666c0828d1111

display: (Optionally) delay focus changes in focus-follows-mouse mode

Moving focus immediately on crossing events as we currently do
in focus-follows-mouse mode may trigger a lot of unwanted focus
changes when moving over unrelated windows on the way to a target.
Those accidental focus changes

 - prevent features like GNOME Shell's application menu from
   working properly

 - and are visually expensive since we now use a very distinct
   style for unfocused windows.

Instead, delay the actual focus change until the pointer has stopped
moving.
```

*(Commit message reformatted to emphasize the reasons.)*

Comment: This thread is a bit old, but I was struggling with this on ubuntu 18.04 and found I also needed to disable `focus-change-on-pointer-rest` in `org.gnome.shell.extensions.classic-overrides`.

Comment: For those (like me) struggling to work out the syntax of the command line:
`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides focus-change-on-pointer-rest false`

Comment: On 18.04, I had to set `focus-change-on-pointer-rest` on `org.gnome.mutter`; setting it on `org.gnome.shell.overrides` and `org.gnome.shell.extensions.classic-overrides` had no effect.

Answer (score 8):

`$ gsettings set org.gnome.mutter focus-change-on-pointer-rest false`

This worked for me in Gnome 3.30.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/956467)

Comment: While your post answers the question and it looks worthy, please write some textual explanation, what it does and how. Do it quickly, a vote is going on about its deletion.

Comment: @Burgi The answer looks very hardcore and useful, I suggest leniency. I would happily extend it to avoid the closure, but not even I can do it.

Comment: + Gnome 3.36 works too.

Comment: How this is not the default, I will never understand. Thank you for the one-line fix!